# Different surname in university ID and passport

Tags: visas, india, netherlands

I have been sponsored by my university to attend a 5 day program abroad. I am confused whether to apply for visa and flight ticket in my maiden name (same as in my University ID card) or with my husband's surname(as in my passport). Please guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visas must generally match the passports with which they are associated.  Furthermore, when you check in for your flight, you will have to show your passport and visa to the airline.  Use your name as shown in your passport for both the visa application and the airline booking.

If you need to show your university ID to anyone, have a copy of your marriage certificate handy to document the name difference.